# Increase recent clipboard pastes in Resharper?

Tags: resharper, resharper-8.2

i'm using Resharper 8.2.

Looking at <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> :

[image]

There are only 19 entries for history pastes.

**Question:**

Is there any file edit / setting edit that will allow me to increase the number of history entries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, sorry. It's a hard coded limit. If you have that many entries, you might want to store them as some kind of snippet, either by dragging the text snippet to Visual Studio's Toolbox window, or by creating a ReSharper Live Template in the Templates Explorer.